# ImportError: No module named modelsinspector

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

I get the following error when I do syncdb

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 18, in handle_noargs
    loaded_models = get_models()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 167, in get_models
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
      .
      .
      .
      .
    from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
ImportError: No module named modelsinspector
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why have you installed South 0.5? The current version of South is 0.7.3 - 0.5 is more than two years old and dates from before the reorganisation that added the `modelsinspector` module. Delete that version and install the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing module modelsinspector. Install it.

Comment: Can you please suggest where can I find it? <br/>I have already installed south 0.5. <br/>My understanding is modelsinspector is a part of south 0.5. Correct me if I am wrong.